# No elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ with everywhere good reduction

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to prove that there aren't any elliptic curves $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with everywhere good reduction. I first suppose that $\Delta = \pm 1$ and am trying to reduce the quantities for $c_{4}, c_6, \Delta$ etc. modulo 8 in order to eventually reach a contradiction. Going off of the hint in Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (exercise 8.15), I'm running into some problems trying to prove that $a_1$, i.e. the coefficient of $xy$ in Weierstrass equation of $E$, is odd. My thinking is that I need to work with

$$\Delta = \pm 1 \equiv -b_2^2b_8 - 3b_6^2 +b_2b_4b_6 \pmod{8}$$

Am I right in thinking this? I've been working with it to no avail. Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not work with the Weierstrass equation of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ with discriminant $\Delta=4a^3+27b^2$?

Comment: The hint used gestured towards the form I mentioned but also: I believe the discriminant is $\Delta = -16(4A^3 + 27B^2)$ for that form of WE of E, making it congruent to 0 modulo 8 and not particularly useful? I'm sure there are other ways but I know for sure that the congruences mod 8 work. I believe I have the steps after showing that $a_1$ is odd that it leads to a contradiction but I have yet to show that it is odd if we assume that $\Delta = \pm 1$.

Comment: If that's your discriminant, then it is a multiple of $16$ so certainly never equal to $\pm1$.

Comment: Yeah true! I must have something wrong then for it to be that trivial of an exercise, which I doubt it is...

Comment: Well, it’s been a long time since I was immersed in this stuff, and believe me, I’ve lost a lot of of what I knew, and even that was a partial understanding. Tate’s original proof involved coming up with a (universal) elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$ that had no $\Bbb Q$-points, and I don’t see that here.

Beyond that, you seem to be looking for what Silverman has called “a global minimal Weierstrass equation”, but there’s no reason, seems to me, that you couldn’t have a good W-equation over, say $\text{Spec}(\Bbb Z_S)$, and *another* good Weierstrass equation over…

Comment: , say $\text{Spec}(\Bbb Z_{S'})$, where the two models agreed over the intersection of these two open subsets of $\text{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$. After all, the discriminant is not an invariant of the elliptic curve, just of the particular Weierstrass equation. So, if what I say is right, it’s not enough to look for a $\Bbb Z$-Weierstrass equation with discriminant $\pm1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coefficient $a_1$ is even, then 
$$b_2=a_1^2+4a_2\equiv0\pmod{4}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
b_4=2a_4+a_1a_3\equiv0\pmod{2}.$$
It follows that
$$\Delta=-b_2^2b_8-8b_4^3-27b_6^2+9b_2b_4b_6\equiv5b_6^2\pmod{8}.$$
This can never be congruent to $\pm1\pmod{8}$. Hence $a_1$ is odd, from which point you say you can conclude the proof.

Alternatively, as noted in the comments any elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$ has a Weierstrass form
$$y^2=x^3+ax+b,$$
with discriminant $\Delta=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$, which cannot equal $\pm1$ as it is a multiple of $16$.

Comment: There's a little subtlety. The elliptic curve has the simplified Weierstrass form, but that simplification can change the reduction type at $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Exactly! It only works if the characteristic of the field your elliptic curve is over isn't 2 or 3!.

Comment: You need to work with a minimal model; the short Weierstrass form certainly needn't be minimal at $2$.